# python dictionary update key's value

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

here is my code:

```
#...existing code
print(serializer.data)
if group.member.filter(id=user).exists():#<-- this is true
    serializer.data['joined'] = True
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
    
print(serializer.data)
```

the result shows like this:

> {'id': 6, 'name': 'ffff', 'joined': False}

> 1

> {'id': 6, 'name': 'ffff', 'joined': False}

why **'joined':'False'** in two places?

it should be **joined:True** in my last print.

where is the problem?

Comment: What is `type(serializer.data)`, it might not be a dict. And what if you print `serializer.data` before the `print(1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django, the `Serializer.data` property returns an OrderedDict, which is constructed using `serializer._data`, but the return value is not `serializer._data` itself.

```
# In class Serializer(BaseSerializer)
@property
def data(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'initial_data') and not hasattr(self, '_validated_data'):
        msg = (
            'When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you '
            'must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the '
            'serialized `.data` representation.\n'
            'You should either call `.is_valid()` first, '
            'or access `.initial_data` instead.'
        )
        raise AssertionError(msg)

    if not hasattr(self, '_data'):
        if self.instance is not None and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
            self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
        elif hasattr(self, '_validated_data') and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
            self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
        else:
            self._data = self.get_initial()
    return self._data
```

Thus, you should keep the copy of return values and modify the value as follows:

```
# keep the return value of serializer.data
serialized_data = serializer.data
print(serializer_data)
if group.member.filter(id=user).exists():
    serializer_data['joined'] = True
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
    
print(serializer_data)
```

Comment: Great answer. Really help me in understanding too, thanks.

Comment: [Relevant line in the DRF github](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L233)

Comment: @Sayse Thanks, I updated answer according to your comment.